# google-api-python-client : Generate oauth URL

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, uri, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Working with google-api-python-client for the first time, I'm trying to generate a "link" in my authorization flow that I can pass to a user for them to allow the app to access their calendar, then I need google to pass-back the token to my app.

Currently I have something like this (basically the getcredentials() function from the quickstart demo, with user-specific tokens and WebApplication credentials.json):

```
def find_creds(user_id):
    creds = None
    token_pickle = f'./credentials/{user_id}.token.pickle'

    if os.path.exists(token_pickle):
        with open(token_pickle, 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'OAUTH.json', SCOPES)  # Google WebApplication.json for OAUTH
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(token_pickle, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds
```

This would work great if the user was running my application locally, however the issue is it's prompting on the server (vm) for a login, rather than passing the request to my users. No bueno.

The users are accessing my application through another application (which I don't control), so I can't really serve them a page to authorize the app - though I could pass them a URL/link to click.

This introduces a few new hurdles since the user isn't logging in locally, so I can't just "save" their authorization token.

The Authorization "flow" I'm trying to achieve should be (I think) something like this:

1. Pass the user a google authorization URL (I'm not sure how to generate this url/link, though I think it can be done with the `google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow` class. Maybe using authorization.url?)
2. User Authorizes app to access limited scope (calendar)
3. Google returns the users token back to my app (I guess this will need to be done via a return URi? So I think my server will need to run apache and have a listener running to collect/store credentials accordingly)

In tackling that first step, I'm already getting stuck though. I suspect that my `flow` object needs to change but I'm having a difficult time finding documentation on `InstalledAppFlow`:

Does it sound like I'm on the right track here? Any help/tips (or documentation) on `InstalledAppFlow` or `google.oauth2.credentials` class would be helpful too. 
I've read through [google-auth-library-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/oauth2/credentials.py) so far without figuring it out.

Comment: The Google OAuth endpoint is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth. This URI is appended with additional information including the Redirect URI. You need to create an OAuth Client in the Google Cloud Console and specify the Redirect URI that calls back to your web server. You receive a code and then exchange the code for tokens (at your web server and not at the client). This process is very easy to implement and does not require any libraries. I wrote an article on how to do this with curl. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: Awesome - Thanks John, I'll check it out!

Comment: @JohnHanley : Thanks again, with your example I was able to get everything working. 

If you get the chance -- Would you mind posting the link to your example as an "answer"? That way I can mark it as the 'solution' and close this one out.